# Maven fails on maven-remote-resources-plugin: Error finding remote resources manifests

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-nifi

When trying to build a mixed Java/Scala project (a custom NiFi processor, using the `org.apache.nifi:nifi-processor-bundle-archetype` project), the build (`mvn clean compile`) fails at an early stage with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: \
maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (process-resource-bundles) \
on project nifi-example-processors: Error finding remote resources manifests: \
/home/user/code/example/nifi-example-processors/ \
target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF/NOTICE \
(No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

The same build works on another machine (Ubuntu 18) but not this Centos 6 machine. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

The error message is misleading.

The problem is that the `target` subdirectory cannot be created. Strangely, Maven doesn't give an error about this, but instead gives an error when one of the expected files within that subdirectory is missing.

In the process of copying  the project from one machine/network to another, the top-level directories within the project (`nifi-example-processors` etc) lost their write permission.

To fix this, simply add write permission (`chmod -R u+w`) to these directories (and check their ownership is as expected!).

Comment: most helpful, saved my day.